# Codeigniter Database Record retrival - Best Practise - Performance

Tags: php, mysql, performance, codeigniter

I'm checking an PHP project which is build using PHP Codeigniter. I'm new to PHP, I like to get your valuable feedback

To retrieve name and item number in php library/controller, call is made to Item Model as below

```
'name'=>$this->CI->Item->get_info($item_id)->name
'item_number'=>$this->CI->Item->get_info($item_id)->item_number
```

I suspect above two line of code will make two independent database sql call instead of one call to retrive the two column of same table. Ie., there will be performance degrade. But somebody can please let me know whether it fires two sql statements please?

I think we need to handle like object

```
$row = $this->CI->Item->get_info($item_id);
echo $row->name;
echo $row->item_number;
```

Please suggest. Thanks in advance.

Model Function:

```
function get_info($item_id)
    {
        $this->db->from('items');
        $this->db->where('item_id',$item_id);

        $query = $this->db->get();

        if($query->num_rows()==1)
        {
            return $query->row();
        }
        else
        {
            //Get empty base parent object, as $item_id is NOT an item
            $item_obj=new stdClass();

            //Get all the fields from items table
            $fields = $this->db->list_fields('items');

            foreach ($fields as $field)
            {
                $item_obj->$field='';
            }

            return $item_obj;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You have made the correct thing... You don't need help on that.

Comment: I think it will make 2 separate queries, Anyway you can enable profiler & see for yourself what's taking up time & how many queries are being executed.